# Double Value from textview

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Iam very sure there is a bunch of similar questions around here but none of them helped me to solve this problem I have.

Lets say I have a Main menu, a Dashboard Layout, and there is 4 buttons. A,B,C,D

when I press A, Iam starting new activity A. And in this Activity A, there is a link Iam getting json items from. it working fine with normal URL but when iam trying to get value from edit-text / textview its crashing.

```
 String url = "http://webservice.xxx.com/webservice/getLocationList.php?lat="+ latValue +"&lng="+ lngValue +"";
```

**latValue** and **lngValue** is from a editbox in my **R.id.test** here is the XML file for EditText

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/test"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/latValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="54.9933628" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lngValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="9.8595655"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

And here I want get the value from it and put it in the link.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


                  EditText lat_source = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.latValue);
here crash -->    Double sourceLat = Double.parseDouble(lat_source.getText().toString());


    EditText lng_source = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lngValue);
    Double sourceLng = Double.parseDouble(lng_source.getText().toString());


    String url = "http://webservice.xxx.com/webservice/getLocationList.php?lat="+ sourceLat +"&lng="+ sourceLng +"";

    Log.d(TAG, "My URL is = " + url);
```

**Log**

```
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.LocationBased.onCreate(LocationBased.java:69)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
    02-15 11:37:41.826: E/AndroidRuntime(14267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

Comment: is R.layout.main the layout which contains the two edit text?

Comment: change Double to double data type.

Comment: whats the use of converting it to double directly pass as string to the url.

Comment: No its not, its R.layout.test

Comment: then you should use R.layout.test or inflate it and use the object returned by the inflater in order to get the EditText object

Comment: I think you don't have an EditText with id R.id.latValue in main.xml but you might have it in another xml

Comment: Is there any example I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(this);
LinearLayout testLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null)
EditText lat_source = (EditText)testLayout.findViewById(R.id.latValue);
Double sourceLat = Double.parseDouble(lat_source.getText().toString());
```

As mentioned, in order to get the `EditText` object through `findViewById`, your view should be added to the View Hierarchy,   through `setContentView`, or you can use an inflater and use the view's object returned by the inflater to get the `EditText`

Comment: thank you very much @blackbelt it working like it supposed too. I didnt know about this inflater stuff, but now i have a solution and i understand what is going on.